# Using Scala extension of immutable class in Java

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, casting, scala-java-interop

I have a Scala class `EMCC` which extends `TreeMap[Long,HashSet[DSFrame]]`

I have a Java class in which I am attempting to create an `EMCC` and add a new key-value pair to it. I can create a new EMCC instance fine, but since TreeMap is immutable, I cannot simply call

```
emcc.insert(key, value)
```

but must instead call

```
emcc = emcc.insert(key,value)
```

Attempting to compile this yields the following error:

```
error: incompatible types
[javac]             emcc = emcc.insert(key, value);
[javac]                               ^
[javac]   required: EMCC
[javac]   found:    TreeMap<Object,Set<DSFrame>>
```

Attempting to cast the insertion result to an EMCC only yields the same error.

How do I make these play well together?

One thing I notice is that it is reporting that the keys of the result are Objects, which is odd because in this situation `key` is a long, but I'm not sure if that's related.

Comment: I don't know scala very well, but can't you use composition instead?

Comment: @fge: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Have a `TreeMap` as an instance member, and delegate the needed operations to it.

Comment: I could, but I assumed that extending TreeMap with domain-specific methods would be cleaner than wrapping the map and its methods up in another class.

I may have been wrong.

Comment: Well, extending a `Collection` is downright dangerous. For one, you don't know whether overriding `.add()`, for instance, would have an influence on `.addAll()`. I believe all concrete implementations of `Collection` or derivates are `final` in the JDK for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend your TreeMap with domain-specific methods I see two possible solutions.

composition

```
class EMCC(private val map: TreeMap[Long, HashSet[DSFrame]] = TreeMap.empty[Long, HashSet[DSFrame]]) {
  def insert(key: Long, value: HashSet[DSFrame]) = new EMCC(map + (key -> value))
  def foo = map.size
}
var e = new EMCC
e = e.insert(23L, HashSet.empty[DSFrame])
println(e.foo)
```

or implicit classes

```
type EMCC = TreeMap[Long, HashSet[DSFrame]]
implicit class EmccExt(map: EMCC) {
  def foo = map.size
}
var e = new EMCC
e = e.insert(23L, HashSet.empty[DSFrame])
println(e.foo)
```